Azurite example to localhost using https with self signed SSL certificate does not work
I'm trying to use azurite with self signed SSL certificate on macOS.
I've create the certificate with:
openssl req -x509 -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout localhost.key -out localhost.crt -days 365 -config openssl.cnf
sudo keytool -delete -alias localhost  -keystore "$JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts
sudo keytool -import -alias localhost -file localhost.crt -keystore $JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit
azurite --location blobstorage --key localhost.key --cert localhost.crt --oauth basic

I run azurite as follows:
azurite --location blobstorage --key localhost.key --cert localhost.crt --blobHost localhost 

I test the connection with curl like this:
curl --cacert localhost.crt https://localhost:10000/devstoreaccount

On console I see:
azurite --location blobstorage --key localhost.key --cert localhost.crt --blobHost localhost 
(node:81129) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
Azurite Blob service is starting at https://localhost:10000
Azurite Blob service is successfully listening at https://::1:10000
Azurite Queue service is starting at https://127.0.0.1:10001
Azurite Queue service is successfully listening at https://127.0.0.1:10001
Azurite Table service is starting at https://127.0.0.1:10002
Azurite Table service is successfully listening at https://127.0.0.1:10002
::1 - - [11/Nov/2024:10:13:15 +0000] "GET /devstoreaccount HTTP/1.1" 400 -

And I get no error message from the curl.
So I think my SSL certificate works.
I then run the following Java code adapted from the example (I've tried numerous variations to this theme):
package mypackage;

import com.azure.storage.blob.BlobServiceClient;
import com.azure.storage.blob.BlobServiceClientBuilder;
import com.azure.storage.common.StorageSharedKeyCredential;
import com.azure.storage.blob.BlobClient;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class AzuriteBlobUploadExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String containerName = "testcontainer";

        BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient;

        if (false) {
            String accountName = "devstoreaccount1";
            String accountKey = "Eby8vdM02x/no2l0DUQ4hFQ2gYbIFZz4NcsZ6bzLz2JIYLzK6i7Az8mB/c7hPt4mQ6ySam/Y3rWFs/37P0Hq9w==";
            StorageSharedKeyCredential credential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(accountName, accountKey);
            blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder().credential(credential).endpoint(String.format("https://localhost:10000/devstoreaccount1")).buildClient();
        } else {
            String connectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=devstoreaccount1;AccountKey=Eby8vdM02x/no2l0DUQ4hFQ2gYbIFZz4NcsZ6bzLz2JIYLzK6i7Az8mB/c7hPt4mQ6ySam/Y3rWFs/37P0Hq9w==;BlobEndpoint=https://localhost:10000/devstoreaccount1;";

            blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder().connectionString(connectionString).buildClient();
        }
        blobServiceClient.getBlobContainerClient(containerName).createIfNotExists();

        try {
            String blobName = "sample.txt";
            BlobClient blobClient = blobServiceClient.getBlobContainerClient(containerName).getBlobClient(blobName);

            String filePath = "sample.txt";

            Files.write(Paths.get(filePath), "This is a test file for Azurite storage.".getBytes());

            blobClient.uploadFromFile(filePath, true);

            System.out.println("File uploaded to Azurite successfully.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

And this fails with:
SLF4J(W): No SLF4J providers were found.
SLF4J(W): Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J(W): See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details.
Exception in thread "main" com.azure.storage.blob.models.BlobStorageException: If you are using a StorageSharedKeyCredential, and the server returned an error message that says 'Signature did not match', you can compare the string to sign with the one generated by the SDK. To log the string to sign, pass in the context key value pair 'Azure-Storage-Log-String-To-Sign': true to the appropriate method call.
If you are using a SAS token, and the server returned an error message that says 'Signature did not match', you can compare the string to sign with the one generated by the SDK. To log the string to sign, pass in the context key value pair 'Azure-Storage-Log-String-To-Sign': true to the appropriate generateSas method call.
Please remember to disable 'Azure-Storage-Log-String-To-Sign' before going to production as this string can potentially contain PII.
Status code 403, "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Error>
  <Code>AuthorizationFailure</Code>
  <Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of the Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:2ce224a8-b355-4293-833c-8ed05f8a3f9e
Time:2024-11-11T10:15:32.398Z</Message>
</Error>"
    at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invokeWithArguments(MethodHandle.java:733)
    at com.azure.core.implementation.http.rest.ResponseExceptionConstructorCache.invoke(ResponseExceptionConstructorCache.java:56)
    at com.azure.core.implementation.http.rest.RestProxyBase.instantiateUnexpectedException(RestProxyBase.java:356)
    at com.azure.core.implementation.http.rest.AsyncRestProxy.lambda$ensureExpectedStatus$1(AsyncRestProxy.java:127)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:113)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2571)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:171)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.set(Operators.java:2367)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onSubscribe(Operators.java:2241)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:96)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:55)
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:76)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:165)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:129)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHide$SuppressFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxHide.java:137)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:129)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHide$SuppressFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxHide.java:137)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:158)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:129)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:158)
    at reactor.core.publisher.SerializedSubscriber.onNext(SerializedSubscriber.java:99)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen$RetryWhenMainSubscriber.onNext(FluxRetryWhen.java:178)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:158)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoInnerProducerBase.complete(Operators.java:2864)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSingle$SingleSubscriber.onComplete(MonoSingle.java:180)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyInner.onComplete(MonoFlatMapMany.java:261)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.onComplete(FluxContextWrite.java:126)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapConditionalSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:275)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:85)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDoFinally$DoFinallySubscriber.onComplete(FluxDoFinally.java:128)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandle$HandleSubscriber.onComplete(FluxHandle.java:223)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapConditionalSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:275)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDoFinally$DoFinallySubscriber.onComplete(FluxDoFinally.java:128)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandleFuseable$HandleFuseableSubscriber.onComplete(FluxHandleFuseable.java:239)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.onComplete(FluxContextWrite.java:126)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$BaseFluxToMonoOperator.completePossiblyEmpty(Operators.java:2098)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollectList$MonoCollectListSubscriber.onComplete(MonoCollectList.java:118)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeek.java:260)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:144)
    at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundComplete(FluxReceive.java:415)
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundComplete(ChannelOperations.java:445)
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.terminate(ChannelOperations.java:499)
    at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientOperations.onInboundNext(HttpClientOperations.java:800)
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:115)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at com.azure.core.http.netty.implementation.AzureSdkHandler.channelRead(AzureSdkHandler.java:222)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:346)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:318)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1495)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1358)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1407)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:530)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:469)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:290)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1357)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:868)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
    Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: #block terminated with an error
        at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:104)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1779)
        at com.azure.storage.common.implementation.StorageImplUtils.blockWithOptionalTimeout(StorageImplUtils.java:146)
        at com.azure.storage.blob.BlobContainerClient.createIfNotExistsWithResponse(BlobContainerClient.java:374)
        at com.azure.storage.blob.BlobContainerClient.createIfNotExists(BlobContainerClient.java:340)
        at mypackage.reco.AzuriteBlobUploadExample.main(AzuriteBlobUploadExample.java:26)

And I cannot figure out what to do next.
In case it has a bearing here is the openssl config file I use:
3_req ]
subjectAltName     = @alt_names

[ alt_names ]
DNS.1 = localhost
DNS.2 = 127.0.0.1

[ req ]
default_bits       = 2048
default_keyfile    = privkey.pem
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
x509_extensions    = v3_req
prompt = no

[ req_distinguished_name ]
countryName = FI
stateOrProvinceName = Province
localityName = City
organizationalUnitName = Company
commonName = My Name

[ v3_ca ]
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[ alt_names ]
DNS.1 = localhost
DNS.2 = 127.0.0.1
IP.1  = 127.0.0.1


I am not sure you actually need own certificates. It sounds like something missing in the authorization. Connecting with tools like the storage explorer or the Azure CLI works?

SSL to local host definitely seems to require certificates, without them I could not get https to connect. You are right I think that the problem is with something missing from the authorization but that is the trick, what is missing? I've google high and low and tried co-pilot and chatgpt, no luck. I need to check those tools if they work with azurite.

Just noticed that according to the documentation "The emulator supports connection via HTTP only", still I change all refences from https to http and it still gives me the same error

Argh! RTFM
"The emulator supports connection via HTTP only."
From
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-configure-connection-string
